# Editors similar to the one in Mainframes

Tags: vim, editor, vi, ispf

I have been using an editor in Mainframes (ISPF) which I'm very much comfortable with. Now I'm working on a unix system and I'm forced to use VI. VI is good but since I got used to the editor in Mainframes, I'm having a hard time due to the difference in the command set. Is there an editor in unix which is similar to the editor in mainframes?

Comment: I'd recommend taking the time to learn vi, or better, [vim](http://www.vim.org/6k/features.en.txt), simply because it's available on so many different platforms. Once you learn it on Unix, it's the same on the other platforms. It's extremely powerful and that power transfers to the other OSes, so you won't be wasting time relearning, or remembering. I wish I'd had it when I was working on mainframes and Windows systems; Now I use it on those three all the time and it's become my preferred editor as a result.

Comment: ofcourse VI is powerful. But since I've been working on ISPF for years, I'm more comfortable with it and trust me it is equally powerful as VI.

Comment: Oh, I used ISPF on mainframes also. It's just not as easy to find on alternate platforms, which is why I recommend vi/vim.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. But I was hoping if I would be really lucky to get ISPF back in unix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there's at least one free one still maintained: [Hybrid Editor XE](http://www.geocities.jp/sakachin2/index.htm). There are some dead ones and commercial ones at [This page](http://www.planetmvs.com/spfeditor/), including a commercial offering called [uni-SPF](http://www.wrkgrp.com/unispf/index.html).

You might want to google `ISPF Unix` or `SPF Linux` or something similar.

Comment: the description about uni-SPF looks like the think I want. But their download page is not active.